# Creating a @Source annotated method in a @Connector not working as Composite Source

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to create a custom Connector and using annotations (in the title). I can add my connector to the Source side of a new flow, but I cannot add it as one of the sources in a Composite Source component....

What are the coding requirements for that to work?

Relevant code:

```
@Connector(name="foo", friendlyName="Foo")
public class FooConnector {

@Config
FooConfig config;

@Source(sourceStrategy = SourceStrategy.POLLING, pollingPeriod = 1000)
public void beAConnector(String rando, final SourceCallback callback) {
```